# Is there any way to turn a native array into a managed one without copying over the data?

Tags: c++-cli

When I'm accessing a file to get a saved object I currently go through this route:

1. read serialized stream into a native buffer
2. copy native buffer into a managed buffer
3. deserialize (i'm using netserializer)

the copying isn't a huge deal but it seems unnecessary so I'd like to eliminate it, if possible.

I thought I found a clever way to do it by having the stream read function accept a function pointer of char*(*allocFunc)(ItemLengthType) and then read the data directly into the pinned managed array, like this:

```
    array<Byte>^ serBuf;
    itemStream->ReadItem(i, [=](uint32_t len){
        serBuf = gcnew array<Byte>(len);
        pin_ptr<Byte> pData = &serBuf[0];
        return reinterpret_cast<char*>(pData);
    });
```

But epic fail, can't capture managed objects in a lambda function, can't even create a lambda function in a managed class.

The only other alternative I see would be to turn my stream class into a managed one and have it produce a managed array but that class is from another project which I use in many other non CLR related solutions. I'm also not going to create a semi managed branch of that project, just too much bother.

Is there any other way for me to avoid the copying step?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to turn a native buffer into a managed array, but you can still eliminate the copy step.

Use this flow instead:

1. Pin a managed buffer (`array<Byte>`), resulting in a `char*`.
2. read serialized stream into the `char*` as if it were a native buffer.
3. Unpin the managed buffer.
4. Deserialize

To do step 1, just allocate a managed byte array and use `pin_ptr` to get a plain `char*`. Read the data into that, then unpin the array. Then, pass the managed array to your deserializer like normal.

Note that pinning the array should be for short periods of time: Whenever something is pinned, that's extra work for the garbage collector, because in the middle of a big block of memory that it wants to re-arrange, there's this array that you told it not to move.

I would also recommend that you profile your application, and see how much of a performance hit the extra copy from native buffer to managed array is. It's probably much less than you think, in which case I'd favor clear & easy to understand code.